# Установка пакетов через функцию "install_github" язык R

Tags: r, rstudio

Никак не могу обойти ошибку со скачиванием пакетов с Github.
Стоят свежие версии языка R и RStudio. Стоит windows 10, запускаю от админа.
Получаю следующую ошибку:

> could not find function "install_github"

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы скачивать пакеты c Github, Вам необходимо установить и подключить библиотеку `devtools`:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
```

Comment: Да, эту библиотеку я ставил.

Comment: Установилась без ошибок, подключается нормально?

Comment: да http://prntscr.com/lby4pn

Comment: А при подключении библиотеки какой вывод?